# How to plot the wave function after a Hartree-Fock calculation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, ab-initio

I have written a code in Mathematica and have obtained the final energy of the hydrogen molecule. I have used Gaussian basis functions for this calculation. Now I need to plot the ground state wave function. How can I do so? I just know that the ground state wave function is defined as
\begin{align}
  \psi_i &= \sum_{\mu=1}^k C_{\mu i}\phi_{\mu} &
  i &= 1, 2, 3, \dots, k,
\end{align}
where $\phi$ is a basis function. However I don't know how to obtain an expression for the ground state wave function.

Comment: Is not $\phi$ your basis function with coefficients C ? You have to know $\phi$ at xyz, (or equivalent in spherical coords)  for each quantum number. It should then straightforwards.

Comment: If you have calculated the final energy of the molecule, then you must have the final form of the wave function, in HF that should be a slater determinant. Given the general limitations of plotting a function with more the 3 parameters, you'll have to have a pick at what you want to plot.

Comment: @Martin - マーチン yeah you're right, but I don't know where can I find the final form? can you help me?

Comment: For that I would probably have to know (and understand) your code, but I don't speak Mathematica. However, others might. So (if it is not too long) you could include it here.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thanks a lot. My code is very long, so can you introduce me a source or a textbook where the final form of ground state wave function is defined after a HF calculation? In fact I wrote my code 3 years ago and that time I used Szabo's book but now I can't find what I need.

Comment: I would recommend that book. I think it is the most detailed and contains the best mathematics. I don't know of any other source more concise. But if you have understood it before, you'll understand it again. You might want to look for the definition of the density matrix, I remotely recall they called it like that... Good Luck!

Comment: @Martin - マーチン OK, thanks for your hints.